mySQL RDS with IAM Role Access Denied-How to pass [enable-cleartext-plugin=true] to mysql2 in a node.js application?
I am getting access denied when trying to connect to a mySQL RDS instance using IAM Role instead of passing a password, BUT ONLY WHEN I DO IT FROM MY NODE.JS APPLICATION. I am able to successfully connect to the RDS using IAM Role via mysql client (command line) from the same EC2 instance in which the node.js application is hosted.
Possible Root Cause: I guess I need to pass [enable-cleartext-plugin=true] to the mysql2 component in my application, but I have no clue how this parameter is called to add it to the connection object.
Additional Info:

If in my application I use the db user password instead of the token, then I can connect to the RDS successfully

I believe that the RDS, security groups and everything else is properly configured in AWS as well as the db user in mySQL, as I can log into the RDS instance not only from the mysql client (command line) from an EC2 instance (either using password and token), but also from DBeaver (a client installed in my local machine) using the db user password (besides from my node application, when using a password)

The reason I suspect that I need to pass the [enable-cleartext-plugin=true] directive to the mysql2 component from my application is because it is mandatory for you to use it when using IAM with mySQL RDS, and the connection from the mysql client (command line) only works if the directive is passed, as in the command below (if I ommit the --enable-cleartext-plugin, then I also get access denied :


mysql --host= [rds-database-endpoint] --port=3306 **--enable-cleartext-plugin** --user=[user-name] --password=[token generated using @aws-sdk/rds-signer]
This is my function in my node application:
`const mysql = require('mysql2');

async function connectToDb(){

  // Generates the authentication token
  const { Signer } = require("@aws-sdk/rds-signer");

  const signer = new Signer({
    hostname: [aws-rds-databasehost-endpoint],
    port: 3306,
    username: [user-name],
    region: "us-east-2",
  });
  
  const token = await signer.getAuthToken();

  // Connect to the RDS instance
  const dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'host-details',
      user: 'user_name',
      password: token,
      database: 'database-name',
      // I guess here I need to pass something like
      // enableCleartext: true
  });

  return dbConnection;
}`

I tried passing the token generated with the @aws-sdk/rds-signer to the mysql2 component as the password. Also tried passing the enable-cleartext-plugin in the connection object (invented a "enableCleartext: true" parameter)
  const dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'host-details',
      user: 'user_name',
      password: token,
      database: 'database-name',
      // I guess here I need to pass something like
      // enableCleartext: true
  });


https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/pull/1403

Thanks for the prompt answer Phil! I did use [mysql_clear_password] as described in github (which def makes sense and answers my question) but I am still getting access denied. Would you have any other idea of something else that could be missing? I even tested the token generated by the node application and was able to successfully connect to the RDS from the mysql client using this token.

Sorry no. Might be worth raising a new issue against node-mysql2 if it's not working as described.

Thanks. I will update this post with the solution in case I find it.
